# Python fit line to high dimensional points and sample between them

Tags: python, math, line

I have two high-dimensional points (for this example let's consider 5 dimensional).

```
p0 = [2 4 1 3 9]
p1 = [5 2 1 0 8]
```

I want to fit a line (hyperplane) between them and then sample a random point (p2) from the line that is between the two original points. p2 is not necessarily the midpoint between the two points, but anywhere along the line. The image below shows what that would look like in 2-dimesions. How would I do that in python? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How would you do that not-in-Python? Start there, give it a try, and post your results if they don't work out.

Comment: This is definitely a line and not a hyperplane. To uniquely determine a hyperplane in dimension n, you need n points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parametrize this line segment as `p2 = p0 + t*(p1-p0)` with parameter `t` in range `[0, 1]`.

Doing this in code:

```
import numpy as np

p0 = [2, 4, 1, 3, 9]
p1 = [5, 2, 1, 0, 8]

p0 = np.array(p0)
p1 = np.array(p1)

dp = p1 - p0

t = np.random.rand(1)[0]

p2 = p0 + t*dp
print(p2)
```

Note that `np.random.rand()` selects from range `[0, 1)`, so there is some small chance for `p2 == p0`.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering Michael. I knew how to do this in 2-D but didn't know how to do this in high dimensions and turns out that it is the same formula